# Fix required for veracode CWE-ID 73 issue in typescriptServices.js

Tags: veracode

We are using monaco editor in our application and that in turn uses typescriptServices.js. We have few veracode issues that belongs to **73 External Control of File Name** or Path category reported in this file. How do we fix these issues?

As this is third party js we cannot fix this issue by modifying the code directly. Is there any new version of this file available that fixes this security issue.